# Conversion of integer to double

Tags: c++, c, math

I need to determine the standard deviation of a set of inputs. This requires the summation of (each input - the mean)^2. I have the following code to do this (510 is an example input for testing):

```
int testDiff = 510;       
console.printf("testDiff = %i \r\n",testDiff);

double testDiff_double = static_cast<double>(testDiff);
console.printf("testDiff_double = %d \r\n",testDiff_double);

double result = pow(static_cast<double>(testDiff),2);
console.printf("result = %d \r\n",result);
```

However, this code does not generate the expected output (260100). If I print the values obtained at each stage, I get the following:

```
testDiff = 510
testDiff_double = 0
pow = 0
```

Why is the conversion from integer to double failing? I am using a static_cast, so I was expecting an error at compile time if there was a logical issue with the conversion.

Note (while it shouldn't matter): I'm running this code on an MBED microcontroller.

Comment: Or use the C++ streams as it will avoid errors like this and do the correct thing because the compiler selects how to print the type.

Comment: %d -> %f , %d is for integers.

Comment: Not related but you might be interested : the way you compute standard deviation have accuracy problems, checkout this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `%d` rather than `%f` to display the floating-point values.

Comment: Yeah -- that would do it. I should stop working on this so late at night. I deal with "math" so little during programming, I forgot it is %f instead of %d...

Answer (score 2):

In your printf functions, try using %f instead of %d.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `%f` or `%e` or `%E` or `%g` in order to display a double/float number.

From the [`printf` reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) :

```
c   Character   
d or i  Signed decimal integer
e   Scientific notation (mantise/exponent) using e character
E   Scientific notation (mantise/exponent) using E character
f   Decimal floating point  
g   Use the shorter of %e or %f
G   Use the shorter of %E or %f
o   Unsigned octal
s   String of characters
u   Unsigned decimal integer
x   Unsigned hexadecimal integer    
X   Unsigned hexadecimal integer (capital letters)
p   Pointer address
n   Nothing printed. The argument must be a pointer to a signed int, where the number of characters written so far is stored.   
%   A % followed by another % character will write % to stdout.
```